# How do I check whether a set of strings appears in a list of pre-defined sets in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new to VBA and this is quite tricky to explain, but hopefully the examples below will show what I'm trying to do.

I've previously used the following function:

```vb
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

To return whether a specified string is contained within a list of values, like so:

```vb
Dim CL3(3) as String
CL3(0) = item1
CL3(1) = item2
CL3(2) = item5

If IsInArray(someValue, CL3) Then SomeAction
```

However, now I'm trying to check whether a specified set of strings appears in a particular list of sets.

I have strings `a`, `b`, and `c`. The values of these are retrieved from a worksheet:

```vb
Dim a, b, c As String
a = Range(SomeCell1).Value
b = Range(SomeCell2).Value
c = Range(SomeCell3).Value
```

I'd like something similar to when I was just trying to check a single string, like follows:

```vb
Dim CL3(8) as Variant
CL3(0) = item1, item2, item3
CL3(1) = item2, item1, item4
CL3(2) = item5, item3, item6
...
CL3(7) = item3, item4, item1
```

There are a number of different `item`s, however there are only 8 possible valid combinations of these. The `item`s may be assigned to `a`, `b`, `c` in any order, so the order defined in the list will not necessarily correspond to the order of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

If possible I'd also like to know which of `a`, `b`, and `c` is the first, second, and third `item` according to the set in the defined list.

I'd also like to be able to do this with sets containing 4 items and sets containing 5 items.

So, to summarise, I'd like to:

- Define a list of sets
- Check if a given `a`, `b`, and `c` are one of the specified sets
- If so, do `SomeAction` involving the first `item` in the specified set
- Loop to next `a`, `b`, `c` (no set number to loop through)

Thank you.

Comment: I would avoid using `Filter` to match items in an array unless you're happy getting a match when the search value is a substring of one of the array values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (almost) pseudo-code (untested) for the main issue:

```
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
a = Range(SomeCell1).Value
b = Range(SomeCell2).Value
c = Range(SomeCell3).Value

Dim CL3(8) as Variant
CL3(0) = Array(item1, item2, item3)
CL3(1) = Array(item2, item1, item4)
CL3(2) = Array(item5, item3, item6)
...
CL3(7) = Array(item3, item4, item1)

Dim i As Long
Dim foundabc As Boolean
For i = 0 to 7
    If IsInArray(a, CL3(i)) Then
        If IsInArray(b, CL3(i)) Then
            If IsInArray(c, CL3(i)) Then
                foundabc = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

If foundabc Then SomeAction
```

Comment: This is doing exactly what I needed! Fantastic, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do something similar. It's not quite the finished product but it should give you some good ideas. Note that **A1:A6** contain my "items" for example:

```
A        B        C
Item1    Item2    Item3
Item2    Item1    Item3
...
```

Then the code is as follows:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each rng In Sheet1.Range("A1:C6").Rows
        For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            Select Case UCase(rng.Cells(1, i).Value)
                Case "A", "B", "C"
                    DoSomething rng.Cells(1, 1).Value
            End Select
        Next i
    Next rng
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(str As String)
    'Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim CL3(3) As Variant, T, arrpos()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long,  m

    CL3(0) = Array("item1", "item2", "item3")
    CL3(1) = Array("item4", "item5", "item6")
    CL3(2) = Array("item7", "item9", "item8")
    CL3(3) = Array("item5", "item6", "item7")
    '....rest of your series here

    T = Array("item7", "item8", "item9")
    ReDim arrpos(LBound(T) To UBound(T))

    For i = LBound(CL3) To UBound(CL3)
        For n = LBound(T) To UBound(T)
            m = Application.Match(T(n), CL3(i), 0)
            If IsError(m) Then Exit For

            'got match:store position
            arrpos(n) = m
            If n = UBound(T) Then
                ' we're on the last check, so done...
                Debug.Print "Match at positions " & _
                     Join(arrpos, ",") & " in cl3(" & i & ")"
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Next n
    Next i
End Sub
```